# Integration in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate: $$\int_C\left[\frac{6}{(z-i)^2}+\frac{2}{z-1}+1-3(z-i)^2\right]dt$$
>
> where $C$ is the circle $|z-i|=4$ traversed once counterclockwise.

$C$ in this question is a circle so I must parameterize it, so a suitable parametrization for $C$ is $z(t)=z_0 +re^{it}$, $0 \leq t \leq\pi$, correct? I can split up the integrate into four parts. If someone can help me get started in the first part corresponding to: $$\int_C\frac{6}{(z-i)^2}dt$$

then I am sure that I will be able to do the rest. Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is homework. If so, I suspect that you are not meant to explicitly evaluate the integral as the value can be read off directly from the expansion you have.

Comment: @copper.hat No, it is not homework. It is practice problems I am doing. The answer is $0$ which I dont understand why?

Comment: There are certain theorems which make this problem rather trivial. Are there any restrictions to what you can use?

Comment: @EuYu One theorem that I know I can use is $\int^b_af(z(t))z'(t)dt$

Comment: Try the residue theorem. (I suspect the answer should be $4 \pi i $.)

Comment: Also, a parameterization of $C$ would be $z(t) = i+ 4 e^{it}$, wth $t \in [0,2 \pi]$ (ie, not $\pi$).

Comment: @copper.hat I havent been taught the residue theorem yet. But the answer is $4\pi i$ . It says to use $\int^b_af(z(t))z'(t)dt$ formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you do not have access to Cauchy's integral formula. I will solve the first part of the integral directly, I will leave the rest to you as you requested.

Parameterizing $C$ as $4e^{it} + i$, we have
$$\oint_C\frac{6}{(z-i)^2}\ dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{24ie^{it}}{16e^{2it}}\ dt = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{6i}{4}e^{-it}\ dt$$
The function $e^{-it}$ is holomorphic, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{6i}{4}e^{-it}\ dt = -\frac{6}{4}e^{-it}\bigg|^{t=2\pi}_{t=0} = 0$$

Comment: A couple of questions Euyu, why is there an $i$ in $24ie^{it}$ and how did you get that answer directly? Also, you used the $\int^b_af(z(t))z'(t)dt$ formula to get the denominator corerct?

Comment: @Q.matin The $i$ comes from the derivative of $i + 4e^{iz}$. Remember that we not only substitute the value of the parameterization, but also multiply by it's derivative (the $z'(t)$ term) when taking the integral. The transition from the contour integral into $$\int_a^bf(z(t))z'(t)\ dt$$ is the first equality.

Comment: Ah, now I see what I did wrong. When I used the formula I ignorantly only used it once for the denominator and did not use it for the numerator as well. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Q.matin You're very welcome. Try your hand with the rest of the question, if you have any problems then I will be happy to help later.

Comment: One last question, why did the $i$ disappear at the end?

Comment: @Q.matin The $i$ disappeared at the end because we integrated $e^{-ix}$, which introduced a term of $\frac{-1}{i}$.